# Playing different audio files based on video keyframe

Tags: javascript, html5, audio

The general idea of this function is to load a different sound file depending on current time position of the video. I have the following information about audio files:

```
var samples: [ 
['00:00:05', 'audio/1.mp3'],
['00:01:00', 'audio/2.mp3']
]
```

The first element contains the end time for specific audio sample, and the second is the sample. I think we don't need the start time, because the following condition should return a good result:

```
if( video.currentTime <= endTime ) { ... }
```

Anyway, here is the code of function I'm using to check which audio file to play (it's executed when the video is paused):

```
var APP.playAudio = function() { 

    var pAudio = samples; // the array above

            for(var i = 0; i < pAudio.length; i++ ) {

                if( video.currentTime < hms_to_s(pAudio[i][0]) ) {
                    pCurrentAudio = pAudio[i][1];
                    break;
                }

            }
}
```

I'm looking for more tricky and clever way to achieve this. As you see, now we iterate over the `pAudio` array each time the video is paused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to play a certain audio at a certain time? Well, you're in luck. I recently did this in a demo. It wasn't playing audio with video though. It was triggering animations at certain points of the audio, but it should be the same idea.

`<audio>` and `<video>` elements are [`HTMLMediaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)s and have [media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Media_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Media_events).

- If you want to play your mapped audio in real time, there is the `timeupdate` event which is triggered when the current time of the element has changed.
- If you want to play it during pause, then there is the `paused` event.

You can use these events to check the `currentTime` of your element, which in this case is your video. `currentTime` is in seconds. If you want to stick to your `hh:mm:ss` format, you'd need your own converter.

Instead of urls, you should have preloaded audio elements there so that they will play instantly when we need them.

Anyways, here's a sample structure with seconds and audio elements

```
var samples = [
  [5,HTMLAudioElement],
  [10,HTMLAudioElement],
  [15,HTMLAudioElement],
  ...
];
```

Then, hook to the `timeupdate` event of the video, check the current time, and compare with the indicated item in the array. You can use a counter to indicate your current position.

```
var i = 0
//get first audio as current audio and play
var currentAudio = samples[i][1].play();

video.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(){

  //if video time is greater than current audio end time
  if(this.currentTime > samples[i][0]){
    if(currentAudio) currentAudio.pause(); //pause existing audio (maybe do a "seek to zero" to reset)
    currentAudio = samples[++i][1];        //reference next audio as current
    currentAudio.play();                   //play the current audio
  }
});
```